# pytest approach to report multiple failures when iterating

Tags: python, automated-tests, iteration, pytest

New to pytest. I'm using it to perform various checks on a website, with the `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` modules.

Say I'm getting all the a-links on a page and then seeing that they all return 200, it is trivial to put this in a single test. But then a single failure means that the iteration is interrupted and the test ends.

What I want is for all the links to be tested and, if there was at least one failure, a report to be generated saying which failed.

Is there a pytest idiom for dealing with this sort of case? Obviously it has wider application than just checking a-links.

NB I have already discovered `pytest.mark.parametrize` ... but for the moment can't see whether this can be used with iteration of this kind.

Comment: I think you are looking for https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.8.7/parametrize.html#pytest-generate-tests

Comment: You might want to accumulate an array of boolean test results and self.assertTrue(all(testResults)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment *pytest_generate_tests* is the way to go.
You parametrize the fixture *link* using the metafunc object. In the test function you then simple check the return code of every link. Where get all links should return a list of strings containing your links.

```
import requests

def get_all_links():
    return ["https://google.com", "https://invalidurlblahblah.com"]

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    metafunc.parametrize("link", get_all_links())

def test_all_links(link):
    try:
        assert requests.get(link).status_code == 200
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        raise AssertionError("Invalid link")
```

Output

```
pytest_example.py::test_all_links[http://google.com] PASSED                                                                                                                                                 
pytest_example.py::test_all_links[http://invalidurlblahblah.com] FAILED
```

Comment: Thanks very much. With my ISP these both return 200 when http, but the test works OK with https. Also a slight typo... so I'm just going to suggest a minor edit.

Answer (score 0):

## Accumulating the results from testing multiple items in iteratable

To test all items in a sequence and report which items failed, you could store the failures and then use an assertion at the end.

### Example of testing multiple URLs

```
import requests


def test_if_links_valid():
    urls = ["http://google.com", "http://invalidurlblahblah.com/"]
    invalid_urls = []

    for url in urls:
        try:
            requests.get(url)
        except requests.ConnectionError:
            invalid_urls.append(url)

    assert len(invalid_urls) == 0, "all urls should be valid"
```

#### Test output

```
>       assert len(invalid_urls) == 0, "all urls should be valid"
E       AssertionError: all urls should be valid
E       assert 1 == 0
E        +  where 1 = len(['http://invalidurlblahblah.com/'])

test_iteration.py:14: AssertionError
```

## Accumulating the results of multiple assertions

The [**pytest-check**](https://github.com/okken/pytest-check) plugin allows for testing multiple failures per test. It provides the infrastructure for accumulating multiple test failures and then reporting the errors after the test completes.

### README.md

#### Installation

From PYPI:

```
$ pip install pytest-check
```

Or from github.

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/okken/pytest-check
```

#### Usage

Example using import:

```py
import pytest_check as check


def test_example():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = [2, 4, 6]
    check.greater(a, b)
    check.less_equal(b, a)
    check.is_in(a, c, "Is 1 in the list")
    check.is_not_in(b, c, "make sure 2 isn't in list")
```

#### Test results:

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
_________________________________ test_example _________________________________
FAILURE:
assert 1 > 2
  test_check.py, line 14, in test_example() -> check.greater(a, b)
FAILURE:
assert 2 <= 1
  test_check.py, line 15, in test_example() -> check.less_equal(b, a)
FAILURE: Is 1 in the list
assert 1 in [2, 4, 6]
  test_check.py, line 16, in test_example() -> check.is_in(a, c, "Is 1 in the list")
FAILURE: make sure 2 isn't in list
assert 2 not in [2, 4, 6]
  test_check.py, line 17, in test_example() -> check.is_not_in(b, c, "make sure 2 isn't in list")
------------------------------------------------------------
Failed Checks: 4
=========================== 1 failed in 0.11 seconds ===========================
```

Comment: IMHO the first part of the answer is not a specific pytest idiom. For the second part: Using a plugin to perform such a simple task is simply overkill.